# What is the best Magento reward point system?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.4.5, reward-points

I'm looking for the best reward point system that allows the customer to sign up for it, start collecting points and spend it with his order.

I need it to be compatible with Magento 2.4.5-p1.